# Convert a NSString into the name of a Constant

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, constants

I have a bunch of constants declared like this:

```
#define kConstant0  @"Cow"
#define kConstant1  @"Horse"
#define kConstant2  @"Zebra"
```

Elsewhere in code I'm trying to extract the constant value by adding an integer to the string name of the constant:

```
int myInt = 1; // (Actual intValue Pulled From Elsewhere)
myLabel.text = [@"kConstant" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",myInt]];
```

But of course this returns:

```
myLabel.text = @"kConstant1";
```

When I want it to return:

```
myLabel.text = @"Horse";
```

I can't figure out how to convert the NSString @"kConstant1" into the constant name kConstant1.

Any help is appreciated.
lq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it automatically. You have to store the mapping in an NSDictionary, e.g.

```
@implementation MyClass
static NSDictionary* constants;
+(void)initialize {
  constants = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     @"kConstant0", @"Cow",
                                     @"kConstant1", @"Horse", ...,
                                     nil];
}
...

NSString* constantName = [kConstant stringByAppendingString:...];
myLabel.text = [constants objectForKey:constantName];
```

If all those constants are of the form `kConstantN`, it is better to just create an array.

```
static NSString* kConstants[] = {@"Cow", @"Horse", @"Zebra", ...};
...

myLabel.text = kConstants[i];
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks muchly. I was trying to get away from having to create another array just to do this since I have the name of the constant already, albeit in NSString form.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is to avoid #defines for defining constants altogether. Use a `NSString` constant like this instead:

```
NSString * const constant1 = @"Cow";
```

The big benefit is that now the constant has a type and is much better with regard to type safety.

Comment: It is just so much easier to debug and much cleaner. Feel free to upvote the answer ;-).